# Form collection of imbricated form without entity never validates

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am currently working on a "Filters" form to add the possibility for the users to apply filters on item lists. The issue I am facing is that once the form is submitted, the controller considers that the form is empty and invalid.

Dumping what's returned by $form->getData() shows the following:

```
array(1) { ["filters"]=> array(0) { } }
```

There is neither errors nor warnings in the logs. The GUI returns an error on the field of the filter:

> This value is not valid.

However if I modify the Twig widget to change the select's id to anything else, I no longer get the invalid value but the form's data still is an empty array.

Here's the layout of this project:

- a FormType containing one select input, and one text input,
- another FormType that implements the former in a collection,
- The controller, which instantiates and use the form,
- a Twig view of the 2nd FormType,
- and the final Twig page

**FilterSearchType.php**

```
namespace NetDev\CoreBundle\Form\Helpers;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use NetDev\CoreBundle\Form\Helpers\FilterType;

class FilterSearchType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('filters', 'collection', array('type' => new FilterType($options['entity']), 'allow_add' => true,
                                                 'allow_delete' => true, 'by_reference' => false))
            ->add('search', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('filters' => [],
                                     'entity' => null));
    }

    public function getName() {
    return 'search_filter';
    }
}
```

**FilterType.php**

```
<?php

namespace NetDev\CoreBundle\Form\Helpers;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class FilterType extends AbstractType {
    public function __construct($entity) {
        $this->model = $entity;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            /*getFilters returns something like that:
             * ['Column A' => 'column_a', 'Column B' => 'column_b', ...]
             */
            ->add('column_name', 'choice', array('choices' => $this->model->getFilters(true)))
            ->add('search_value', 'text')
            ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(['column_name' => '',
                            'search_value' => '']);
    }

    public function getName() {
    return 'netdev_filter';
    }
}
```

Here is how the form is given to Twig from the controller:

**RoutesController.php**

```
class RoutesController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction($page = 1, Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $orderBy = $request->query->get('orderBy');
        $orderType = $request->query->get('orderType');

        $form = $this->createForm(new RouteManagerType($em), null, array('orderBy' => $orderBy,
                                                                     'orderType' => $orderType));
        $filterForm = $this->createForm(new FilterSearchType(), null, array('entity' => new Route()));

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $filterForm->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            // Never reached, $filterForm is always marked as invalid
            $formData = $filterForm->getData();

            var_dump($formData);
            exit();

            if (!empty($formData['filters']) && count($formData['filters'])) {
                if (empty($formData['action'])) $formData['action'] = 'filter';

                $form = $this->createForm(new RouteManagerType($em), null,
                                          array('orderBy' => $orderBy,
                                                'orderType' => $orderType,
                                                'filters' => $formData['filters']));
            }
    }
```

**Twig widget: filter_search.html.twig**

```
{% block netdev_filter_widget %}
  {% spaceless %}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }} class="form-control" id="search_column">
        {% for group_label, choice in form.column_name.vars.choices %}
          <option value="{{ choice.value }}" {{ block('attributes') }}>{{ choice.label }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-addon">contains</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_criteria" placeholder="search"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've dumped pretty much everything I could and nothing was really interesting. I am not even sure that the Kernel understands / correctly "links" the submit the user has performed and the form the controller created.

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you leave the form theming to the default implementations? Usually the rendering of the names of the form elements is off if you don't get correctly bound data. (i.e. leave netdev_filter_widget out).

Comment: That's the issue ! Nice catch. The <select> node is named "0[column-name]" when using the manual rendering whereas it is named "search_filter_filters_0_column_name" on the builtin twig widget. Plus the builtin correctly works :) If you want to, post this as an answer so that I can grant you the bonus ! Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome of course. I summarized it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the issue is that if you do the rendering yourself, you should very well be aware of the fact that the names as rendered in HTML are exactly what the backend expects, otherwise you'll get issues like these.

The best way to tackle that is take the default form rendering as a starting point and don't do any custom HTML until you're absolutely sure you need custom templating. When you do, inspect the default templates to see how the names of the elements are built, and follow the exact same naming, or even better, reuse base templates wherever possible (either by extending blocks and calling parent() and/or using the `block` function).